# Set limit to media upload?

Tags: uploads, media

I am searching online and all I can see is how to *increase* file size for media upload, which I know how to do with `php.ini`, but what I need to do is limit the file size for media upload only.

The client and his associates have trouble with understanding: Please do not upload images that are bigger than 1MB because your site will load forever.

They keep uploading images that are over 8 MB in size, and the whole site takes over 30 sec to load. It's horrendous.

So I was thinking - if it's possible to limit the image upload to 1 MB or so without affecting the general `upload_max_filesize` which will influence the ability to upload themes and plugins (and I don't want that to happen).

Any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` that allows you to stop the uploading process if a specific condition is not accomplished.

In your case, you could try this code snippet:

```
function limit_upload_size( $file ) {

    // Set the desired file size limit
    $file_size_limit = 1024; // 1MB in KB

    // exclude admins
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

        $current_size = $file['size'];
        $current_size = $current_size / 1024; //get size in KB

        if ( $current_size > $file_size_limit ) {
            $file['error'] = sprintf( __( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );
        }

    }

    return $file;

}
add_filter ( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_upload_size', 10, 1 );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This did the trick, I just removed the excluded admins, so that nobody can upload more than 1 MB. Thanks :D

Comment: Is have added Capiedge's code, however my error message reads: "Error #-200: HTTP Error." Is it possible to replace this message with your own custom one? not sure why the specified error message is not showing up....

Comment: Tip 1: put this at the end of /wp-admin/includes/file.php | Tip 2: works only with non-administrator users

Comment: Is there a way to add a URL in the error message ?

Answer (score 3):

You can hook into `upload_size_limit` and set a maximum filesize:

```
// Change the upload size to 1MB
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'wpse_228300_change_upload_size' ); 
function wpse_228300_change_upload_size()
{
    return 1000 * 1024;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Capiedge was first so I used his code.

Comment: Also, that'd extend the limit to plugin files upload as well. And won't allow you to upload plugins greater than 1 MB in size.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is works great !

```
  function my_max_image_size( $file ) {
  $size = $file['size'];
  $size = $size / 1024;
  $type = $file['type'];
  $is_image = strpos( $type, 'image' ) !== false;
  $limit = 750;
  $limit_output = '750kb';
  if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
    $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
  }
  return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_max_image_size' );
```

Answer (score -3):

**1: Theme Functions File**

There are cases where we have seen that just by adding the following code in the theme function’s file, you can increase the upload size:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

**2. Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file**

In most cases if you are on a shared host, you will not see a php.ini file in your directory. If you do not see one, then create a file called php.ini and upload it in the root folder. In that file add the following code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

**3. htaccess Method**

Some people have tried using the htaccess method where by modifying the `.htaccess` file in the root directory, you can increase the maximum upload size in WordPress. Open or create the `.htaccess` file in the root folder and add the following code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but `@ini_set` usually never works (I think because of the security reasons), and I don't want to touch `php.ini`. The htaccess method seems odd, but still I got the answer above that works :)

Comment: -1 because you didn´t read the question and blatantly copied from here without telling that: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/