# Set different max upload size limits based on file type/extension

Tags: uploads, media-library, limit, media-settings

When uploading with video files to the Media Library, it's apparent that you need to increase the **Max upload file size** value. But this will be applied to all media types, including images and documents.

Is there any way or simple code that can set different size limits based on the file type/extension so that I can grant a large limit for videos, a small limit for images, and a different limit for documents?

I think WordPress should handle this natively because it's not logical to have the same limit for all file types. This was OK in the past when WordPress saw the light for the first time, but not in the current time.

Comment: There are already some good questions with answers that ask about restricting the dimensions and file size of images on the site, but recommendations are off topic here, asking for a plugin will get your question closed and shut down

Comment: I'm asking for a way to have multiple limits for the **Max upload file size** field based on the uploaded file extension. Thank you@TomJNowell.

Comment: I understood that, that's why I left a comment not an answer. Those questions and answers are directly related to your question, with significant overlap, and hold important information that will be needed to answer this question. They may be able to solve your question without any additional help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function max_video_size( $file ) {
  $size = $file['size'];
  $size = $size / 1024;
  $type = $file['type'];
  $is_image = strpos( $type, 'video' ) !== false;
  $limit = 750;
  $limit_output = '750kb';
  if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
    $file['error'] = 'Video files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
  }
  return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'max_video_size' );
```

Rinse and repeat, changing *video* in the **$is_image** line to whatever filetype you want to specify, and even by altering the function, building all desired filetypes into the one filter.

---

FULL DISCLOSURE = the core of this answer is found in [Set limit to media upload?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228300/set-limit-to-media-upload)